# how to make header left side with right and side button in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to how header label left side with button on right side .

i found like this

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
    <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="check" data-theme="b">Save</a>
```

But i need like this [image]

My case label on left side and button on right side

Comment: just answered ur other question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5kfnT/3/

JQM DOC: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/headers/

Custom header configurations

If you need to create a header that doesn't follow the default configuration, simply wrap your custom styled markup in any container, such as div. The plugin won't apply the automatic button logic to the wrapped content inside the header container so you can write custom styles for laying out the content in your header.

It's also possible to create custom bars without using the header data-role at all. For example, start with any container and add the ui-bar class to apply standard bar padding and add the ui-bar-b class to assign the bar swatch styles from your theme. (The "b" can be any swatch letter.)

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">A</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">B</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, override `ui-title` and `ui-btn-right` styles. However, for the second button, give it a custom class in order not to override both button with `ui-btn-right`. I used custom class `.second` for the second button.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PuAPg/)**

**CSS** - I used `.ui-header` in order not to change footer style.

```
.ui-header .ui-title {
   margin-left: 2px !important;
   text-align: left !important;
   width: 150px !important;
}

.second.ui-btn-right {
   right: 80px !important
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="header">
  <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete" class="second ui-btn-right">Cancel</a>
  <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
  <a href="index.html" data-icon="check" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right">Save</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic :-D +1..but wouldnt it be better if you just used `controlgroup` for the buttons? Just asking:)

Comment: @passionateCoder thanks bhai. It's possible, go ahead and _throw your towel_. I'm not going to snatch your idea =)

Comment: Nah. I was just asking.that's not OPS question here. Op wanted the buttons to be aligned which this does perfectly. Just had a doubt if this was better or using control group was better. :-)

Comment: @passionateCoder controlgroup looks better, but you need to think about visitors _finger_ size lol.